# Exact sequence of structure sheaves implies exact sequence of twisted sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Assume I have an onto morphism $\pi: Y\longrightarrow X$, where $X$ and $Y$ are both projective curves over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Also, assume that the following exact sequence of structure sheaves holds:
$$0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X\longrightarrow\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y\longrightarrow k\longrightarrow 0$$

I would like to know whether the former exact sequence also implies that:
$$0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(d)\longrightarrow\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y(d)\longrightarrow k\longrightarrow 0$$

Holds for all $d$.

Comment: Twisting an exact sequence by $\mathcal{O}(d)$ preserves exactness, since $\mathcal{O}(d)$ is a line bundle. If this is what you're doing to the whole sequence, great, it's exact - but if you're doing something else (which might be suggested by not putting a $k(d)$ at the end), you'll have to go in to more detail about what's going on and the answer may change.

Comment: To add a bit to the comment of @KReiser, there is an isomorphism $k(d) \cong k$ induced by a trivialization of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ in a neighborhood of the support of $k$.

Comment: @Sasha good comment, though I guess it depends on exactly what the sheaf structure on $k$ is - if it's a constant sheaf and $d\neq 0$ no such trivialization exists.

Comment: @KReiser I guess that what the OP means is that $X$ is a curve which is not normal at a point and $Y$ is its normalization. Then $k$ is the structure sheaf of the non-normal point of $X$.

Comment: Indeed @Sasha, this is what I am doing. How can I justify the exactness of the latter sequence? Does it follow from taking a tensor product with $\mathcal{O}_X(d)$? Can someone demonstrate how?

Comment: Yes, as @KReiser explained tensor product with a line bundle is an exact functor.

Comment: Why is there an isomorphism between the skyscraper sheaf $k$ and $k(d)$? If $k(d)=k\tensor_{O_X} O_X(d)$, I can see why it is also a skyscraper, but I do not see the isomorphism of its global sections with those of $k$ (the field).

Comment: Because, as I mentioned in my first comment, $\mathcal{O}(d)$ is locally trivial, in particular it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}$ in a neighborhhod of the support of $k$.

Comment: Apologies for being a noob. This now makes sense.